# Linear Algebra: Determine if a triangle is a right angled triangle

Tags: linear-algebra

I've just started my course in Linear Algebra, and I've come across a question I'm not entirely sure how to solve.

> Let $A = (1, 1, -1), B = (-3, 2, -2), C = (2, 2, -4)$. Prove that the
>   triangle $ABC$ is a right-angled triangle.

I know what we need to do, I know that we can use the dot product to find the angle between two vectors, and if the dot product is = 0 that means that we have a right angle.

I'm looking for some hints in the right direction of what I need to. I believe I'll need to construct two vectors from the triangle ($\overrightarrow{AB}$, $\overrightarrow{AC}$, $\overrightarrow{BC}$, etc..?) and then compute the dot product of the two to determine the angle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your method is correct. The three angles in our triangle can be tested by computing the dot product of the following pairs
\begin{align*}
\vec{AB} &= \langle-4,1,-1\rangle & \vec{AC} &= \langle1,1,-3\rangle \\
\vec{BA} &= \langle 4,-1,1\rangle & \vec{BC} &= \langle5,0,-2\rangle \\
\vec{CA} &= \langle-1,-1,3\rangle & \vec{CB} &= \langle-5,0,2\rangle
\end{align*}
These are the *displacement vectors* connecting the points $A$, $B$, and $C$. For example $\vec{AB}=B-A$.

These dot products are
\begin{align*}
\vec{AB}\cdot\vec{AC} &= 0 & \vec{BA}\cdot\vec{BC} &= 18 & \vec{CA}\cdot\vec{CB} &= 11
\end{align*}
What does this say about our triangle?

Comment: How did you construct the vector AB? To answer your question, because we found an dot product of 0, we can say that our triangle does indeed have a right angle.

Comment: By the formula for displacement vectors: $\vec{AB}=B-A$

Comment: Ahh ok, thank you for the edit. I was trying A-B. I understand now.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that "the triangle ABC" means the triangle defined by the three endpoints of $\vec{a}, \vec{b}, \vec{c}$ when the vectors all start from the origin, the three sides of the triangle are given by $\vec{a} - \vec{b}$, $\vec{a} - \vec{c}$, and $\vec{b} - \vec{c}$. Use the dot product of each pair of those vectors to find the angles between them.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use the dot product. Either $\overrightarrow{AB} \cdot \overrightarrow{AC} = 0$ or $\overrightarrow{AB} \cdot \overrightarrow{BC} = 0$, since the dot product of orthogonal vectors is $0$.